# Where can I restore Pandoc's configuration

Tags: pandoc, reveal.js

I have Pandoc 2.2.3.2 installed on my system via Anaconda. The Reveal.js slideshows I convert with it do not work, because the inserted links to the Reveal.js code seem to be wrong. The [documentation states](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#variables-for-html-slides) that the default URL should be 'https://unpkg.com/reveal.js@^4/'. However, in my generated slides they turn out as in for example `<script src="reveal.js/js/reveal.js"></script>`, so the base part of the URL seems to be missing.
Fixing the URL by setting the `revealjs-url` variable is unfortunately not enough, because the files seem to be located under 'dist' rather than the various prefixes 'js', 'css' that I find in my document now.
Where could this be configured in Pandoc? I have searched the documentation and grepped for possible configuration files on my hard drive, with no luck so far.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to fix this by using an URL pointing to a reveal.js 3.* version. The versioning issue has been fixed in newer versions (pandoc 2.10 and later). Instead of always using the latest reveal.js version, pandoc now pins a specific version.

See this [pandoc issue](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/6408) for more details.

Comment: Thanks, I was able to fix it by upgrading Pandoc to 2.10.1. I was previously installing Pandoc through a channel where only an older version was available.